# Black Noise with glass, Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, glass

I'm new to blender so cut me some slack but when it comes to rendering glass I always get black noise on the rendered glass. This doesn't affect other materials so i'm confused on what i'm doing wrong. Please help me.

[image: Heres what i got[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT9ES.jpg)

[image]

Comment: try increasing your transmission samples

Comment: Upped transmission to 6, the noise is reduced but its still there, anyway to get rid of it completely?